# Implicit joins and N:N tables in jOOQ

Tags: sql, jooq

In current jOOQ versions there is a feature to implicitly join tables.

It allows one to 'navigate' using foreign key constraints defined on tables.

Does it also work on `n:n` tables? For example if I have `DOCUMENT`, and `CLIENT`, and a `n:n` table between them `CLIENT_DOCUMENT`, how would I translate the following query to use the new syntax?

```
  db.select(*DOCUMENT.fields())
            .from(DOCUMENT)
            .join(CLIENT_DOCUMENT).onKey()
            .join(CLIENT).onKey()
            .where(CLIENT.CLIENT_NAME.eq(name))
            .fetchInto(Document::class.java)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implicit join feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/), as of jOOQ 3.13, only works for to-one relationships, not for to-many relationships. There are a variety of planned improvements for future versions: [#7536](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7536).

However, a `m:n` relationship can be seen as two to-one relationships starting from the relationship table. You could write:

```java
db.select(CLIENT_DOCUMENT.document().fields())
  .from(CLIENT_DOCUMENT)
  .where(CLIENT_DOCUMENT.client().CLIENT_NAME.eq(name))
  .fetchInto(Document::class.java)
```